# Remote AJAX call from jQuery validate to check email validity not working

Tags: java, jquery, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a remote method call for checking email availability to jQuery validation using a Spring Boot REST API.

When using the remote function from jQuery I can see from the server side the value of the email and the server response, but in the web client it is not displaying the error "Email has been taken".

```
@RestController
public class ValidateController
{   
  @Autowired
    MemberService member;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/checkEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> checkEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email) 
  {
        System.out.println("Requested by ajax validator..." + email);
        boolean _email = this.member.existEmail(email);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(_email, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```js
$('#validation-form').validate({
  errorElement: 'div',
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  focusInvalid: false,
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/easyscan/checkEmail",
        type: "post",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: {
          email: function() {
            return $("#email").val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: "Please provide a valid email.",
      email: "Please provide a valid email.",
      remote: "Email address taken."
    }
  },
```

Comment: If you check the network tab of dev tools you will see the request being made. Check to ensure that the response code is 200. If not please post the result here, and tell us the response text as it should contain an error you can debug

Comment: I have checked the Network tab result as you said and the response code is 200, also in **XHR** Tab in the network i can see the result **True** or **False**. But still can't figure it out why the jquery validator is not displaying the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had with the remote method was that my server was returning JSON with a number of properties, not just true or false, which is what the remote function wants. So, I used the addMethod to drill into the response and just get the value of the JSON property I wanted.

```
$.validator.addMethod("uniqueEmail", function (value, element) {
    let emailOrgName = "yourDomain/uniqueEmailCheck?emailId=" + value;
    let result = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: emailOrgName,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.data.email === 1) {
                console.log(data.data.email + ': This email exists.');
                result = false;
            } else {
                console.log(data.data.email + ': This email does not exist.');
                result = true;
            }
        },
        async: false
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});

$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            uniqueEmail: true,
            normalizer: function (value) {
                return $.trim(value);
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address.",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Your email address must consist of at least {0} character."),
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Your email address must be no longer than {0} characters."),
            uniqueEmail: "Your Email address is already registered on our system.",
        }
    },

    // Bootstrap 4 native error style.

    errorElement: "div",
    errorClass: "is-invalid",
    validClass: "is-valid",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.addClass("invalid-feedback");
        if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
            error.insertAfter(element.next("label"));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```